# How do I make my program connect through a proxy?

Tags: c#, winforms, proxy

I'm working on a program and want it to connect to a proxy.
So there would be a text box and the user would input the IP:Port.  Once they click on a button, it would run through the proxy.  Additionally, the web browsers on my form would also go through the proxy.

How can I do this?

Comment: What sort of proxy do you wish to work with? http proxy? ftp proxy? socks proxy? there are examples on working with proxys for each type, but before anyone can help you, it would probably help them to be a little more specific about your problem, and show what you've tried.

Comment: @BugFinder What kind would the normal proxy be? HTTP I think. Its for a web browser I'm making, so that when they input the IP:Port format it will just start going through the proxy when they browse. What type would that be?

Comment: the IP:Port format is nothing to do with proxies.  It just a means of telling the browser to connect to a different remote port rather than the default of 80.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using normal sockets, you'd simply point the socket to the proxy ip/port. If you're using the winforms webbrowser control, i think it uses whatever proxy settings are set in windows.