# How do I use InternetSetOption?

Tags: c#, proxy, internetsetoption

This question:

[Using Proxy with web browser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203847/using-proxy-with-web-browser-control)

Told me to use "InternetSetOption". How do I use it? How might I implement it in code (example?)?

Thanks!

Comment: For god's sake, @Jacob. You don't ask a new question every time you don't get the answer you want, you edit your question and make it BETTER. You've asked variants of this particular question at least 5 times now.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352780/using-a-proxy-in-c-webbrowser

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247368/how-do-i-access-registry-from-c-for-a-proxy

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247220/how-do-i-use-a-socket-proxy-in-c-webbrowser

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246498/how-do-i-use-a-socket-proxy-in-c-webbrowser

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244642/how-do-i-make-my-program-connect-through-a-proxy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public struct Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO
{
    public int dwAccessType;
    public IntPtr proxy;
    public IntPtr proxyBypass;
}

[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool InternetSetOption(
    IntPtr hInternet,
    int dwOption,
    IntPtr lpBuffer,
    int lpdwBufferLength);

private void RefreshIESettings(string strProxy)
{
    const int INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY = 38;
    const int INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY = 3;

    Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO struct_IPI;

    struct_IPI.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY;
    struct_IPI.proxy = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(strProxy);
    struct_IPI.proxyBypass = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("local");

    IntPtr intptrStruct = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI));

    // Converting structure to IntPtr
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(struct_IPI, intptrStruct, true);

    bool iReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, intptrStruct, Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI));
}

private void Usage()
{
    RefreshIESettings("1.2.3.4:8080");
    object nullObject = 0;
    string strTemp = "";
    object nullObjStr = strTemp;
    axWebBrowser1.Navigate("http://test.com", ref nullObject, ref nullObjStr, ref nullObjStr, ref nullObjStr);
}
```

Comment: It says that 'axWebBrowser1' does not exist in current context. Marshal does not exist in current context. DllImport could not be found. -- What's wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: @Jacob - of course axWebBrowser1 does not exist, because it is an example. You need to replace with the reference to your WebBrowswer control.

Comment: Well, what about 'Marshal' and 'DllImport' - won't work without those?

Comment: @Jacob - for `DllImport` add 'using System.Runtime.InteropServices'