# How to change Windows 7 LAN Settings Programmatically using C#

Tags: c#

Any idea how to do the following for `Windows 7` using `C#`?

`Control Panel` -> `Internet Options` -> `Connections` > `LAN Settings`
Check or Un-check the `CheckBox` saying `Use a Proxy server for your LAN`

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/q/197725/799586

Answer (score 6):

Below is a class I adapted to do exactly this, the proper way (without editing registry) using `InternetSetOption` and `InternetQueryOption`, including notifying the OS and applications of the change so no restart is required.

```
public class InternetSettings
{
    public static bool GetProxyEnabled()
    {
        InternetPerConnOptionList request = new InternetPerConnOptionList();
        InternetPerConnOption[] options = new InternetPerConnOption[1];
        IntPtr optionsPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            options[0].dwOption = OptionType.INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS;

            request.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(InternetPerConnOptionList));
            request.pszConnection = IntPtr.Zero;
            request.dwOptionCount = options.Length;
            request.dwOptionError = 0;

            int optionSize = Marshal.SizeOf(options[0]);

            optionsPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(optionSize * options.Length);

            if (optionsPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return false;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < options.Length; i++)
            {
                IntPtr optionPtr = new IntPtr(optionsPtr.ToInt32() + (i * optionSize));
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(options[i], optionPtr, false);
            }

            request.pOptions = optionsPtr;

            int requestLength = request.dwSize;

            bool result = NativeMethods.InternetQueryOption(IntPtr.Zero, InternetOptionActions.INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION, ref request, ref requestLength);

            if (!result)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < options.Length; i++)
                {
                    IntPtr opt = new IntPtr(optionsPtr.ToInt32() + (i * optionSize));
                    options[i] = (InternetPerConnOption)Marshal.PtrToStructure(opt, typeof(InternetPerConnOption));
                }

                return ((ProxyFlags)options[0].Value.dwValue & ProxyFlags.PROXY_TYPE_PROXY) == ProxyFlags.PROXY_TYPE_PROXY;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (optionsPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(optionsPtr);
            }
        }
    }
    public static bool UnsetProxy()
    {
        InternetPerConnOptionList request = new InternetPerConnOptionList();
        InternetPerConnOption[] options = new InternetPerConnOption[3];
        int optionSize = 0;
        IntPtr optionsPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            options[0].dwOption = OptionType.INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS;
            options[0].Value.dwValue = (int)ProxyFlags.PROXY_TYPE_DIRECT;
            options[1].dwOption = OptionType.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER;
            options[1].Value.szValue = IntPtr.Zero;
            options[2].dwOption = OptionType.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_BYPASS;
            options[2].Value.szValue = IntPtr.Zero;

            optionSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(InternetPerConnOption));
            optionsPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(optionSize * options.Length);

            if (optionsPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return false;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < options.Length; ++i)
            {
                IntPtr optionPtr = new IntPtr(optionsPtr.ToInt32() + (i * optionSize));
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(options[i], optionPtr, false);
            }

            request.pszConnection = IntPtr.Zero;
            request.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(InternetPerConnOptionList));
            request.dwOptionCount = options.Length;
            request.dwOptionError = 0;
            request.pOptions = optionsPtr;

            int requestLength = request.dwSize;

            if (NativeMethods.InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, InternetOptionActions.INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION, ref request, requestLength))
            {
                NativeMethods.InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, InternetOptionActions.INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
                NativeMethods.InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, InternetOptionActions.INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, IntPtr.Zero, 0);

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (optionsPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(optionsPtr);
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < options.Length; i++)
            {
                if (options[i].Value.szValue != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(options[i].Value.szValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static bool SetProxy(string strProxy)
    {
        InternetPerConnOptionList request = new InternetPerConnOptionList();
        InternetPerConnOption[] options = new InternetPerConnOption[2];
        int optionSize = 0;
        IntPtr optionsPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            options[0].dwOption = OptionType.INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS;
            options[0].Value.dwValue = (int)ProxyFlags.PROXY_TYPE_PROXY;
            options[1].dwOption = OptionType.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER;
            options[1].Value.szValue = String.IsNullOrEmpty(strProxy) ? IntPtr.Zero : Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(strProxy);

            optionSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(InternetPerConnOption));
            optionsPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(optionSize * options.Length);

            if (optionsPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return false;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < options.Length; ++i)
            {
                IntPtr optionPtr = new IntPtr(optionsPtr.ToInt32() + (i * optionSize));
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(options[i], optionPtr, false);
            }

            request.pszConnection = IntPtr.Zero;
            request.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(InternetPerConnOptionList));
            request.dwOptionCount = options.Length;
            request.dwOptionError = 0;
            request.pOptions = optionsPtr;

            int requestLength = request.dwSize;

            if (NativeMethods.InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, InternetOptionActions.INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION, ref request, requestLength))
            {
                NativeMethods.InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, InternetOptionActions.INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
                NativeMethods.InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, InternetOptionActions.INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, IntPtr.Zero, 0);

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (optionsPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(optionsPtr);
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < options.Length; i++)
            {
                if (options[i].Value.szValue != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(options[i].Value.szValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static bool SetProxy(string strProxy, string strExceptions)
    {
        InternetPerConnOptionList request = new InternetPerConnOptionList();
        InternetPerConnOption[] options = new InternetPerConnOption[3];
        int optionSize = 0;
        IntPtr optionsPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            options[0].dwOption = OptionType.INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS;
            options[0].Value.dwValue = (int)ProxyFlags.PROXY_TYPE_PROXY;
            options[1].dwOption = OptionType.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER;
            options[1].Value.szValue = String.IsNullOrEmpty(strProxy) ? IntPtr.Zero : Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(strProxy);
            options[2].dwOption = OptionType.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_BYPASS;
            options[2].Value.szValue = String.IsNullOrEmpty(strExceptions) ? IntPtr.Zero : Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(strExceptions);

            optionSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(InternetPerConnOption));
            optionsPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(optionSize * options.Length);

            if (optionsPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return false;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < options.Length; ++i)
            {
                IntPtr optionPtr = new IntPtr(optionsPtr.ToInt32() + (i * optionSize));
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(options[i], optionPtr, false);
            }

            request.pszConnection = IntPtr.Zero;
            request.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(InternetPerConnOptionList));
            request.dwOptionCount = options.Length;
            request.dwOptionError = 0;
            request.pOptions = optionsPtr;

            int requestLength = request.dwSize;

            if (NativeMethods.InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, InternetOptionActions.INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION, ref request, requestLength))
            {
                NativeMethods.InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, InternetOptionActions.INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
                NativeMethods.InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, InternetOptionActions.INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, IntPtr.Zero, 0);

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (optionsPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(optionsPtr);
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < options.Length; i++)
            {
                if (options[i].Value.szValue != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(options[i].Value.szValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #region WinInet structures
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct InternetPerConnOptionList
    {
        public int dwSize;
        public IntPtr pszConnection;
        public int dwOptionCount;
        public int dwOptionError;
        public IntPtr pOptions;
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct InternetPerConnOptionData
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int dwValue;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public IntPtr szValue;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftValue;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct InternetPerConnOption
    {
        public OptionType dwOption;
        public InternetPerConnOptionData Value;
    }
    #endregion

    #region WinInet enums
    //
    // options manifests for Internet{Query|Set}Option
    //
    public enum InternetOptionActions : uint
    {
        INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH = 37,
        INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED = 39,
        INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION = 75
    }

    //
    // Options used in INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTON struct
    //
    public enum OptionType
    {
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS = 1,
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER = 2,
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_BYPASS = 3,
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_URL = 4,
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTODISCOVERY_FLAGS = 5,
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_SECONDARY_URL = 6,
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_RELOAD_DELAY_MINS = 7,
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_LAST_DETECT_TIME = 8,
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_LAST_DETECT_URL = 9
    }

    //
    // PER_CONN_FLAGS
    //
    [Flags]
    public enum ProxyFlags
    {
        PROXY_TYPE_DIRECT = 0x00000001,  // direct to net
        PROXY_TYPE_PROXY = 0x00000002,  // via named proxy
        PROXY_TYPE_AUTO_PROXY_URL = 0x00000004,  // autoproxy URL
        PROXY_TYPE_AUTO_DETECT = 0x00000008   // use autoproxy detection
    }
    #endregion

    internal static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer, int lpdwBufferLength);

        [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool InternetQueryOption(IntPtr hInternet, InternetOptionActions dwOption, ref InternetPerConnOptionList lpOptionList, ref int lpdwBufferLength);

        [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, InternetOptionActions dwOption, ref InternetPerConnOptionList lpOptionList, int lpdwBufferLength);

        [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, InternetOptionActions dwOption, IntPtr lpbuf, int lpdwBufferLength);
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
InternetSettings.SetProxy("192.168.0.2", "(local);myexception.com");
```

and

```
InternetSettings.UnsetProxy();
```

Comment: Finally, this is my solution! Many thanks. I tried to set it programmatically in the registry before, but this did not work for me on windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 0):

I can't put a comment so i would just add it as an answer. You can use the WinINet API calls (InternetSetOption specifically)from c# using I/Invoke to get this done (i agree about not changing registry directly).

Here is the related StackOverflow Answer:

[How do I use InternetSetOption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353715/how-do-i-use-internetsetoption)

This has example code and usage.

Answer (score -1):

In vc++ you can use below code..

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Checks or unchecks the IE Options Connection setting of "Automatically detect Proxy"
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="set">Provide 'true' if you want to check the 'Automatically detect Proxy' check box. To uncheck, pass 'false'</param>
    public void IEAutoDetectProxy(bool set)
    {
        // Setting Proxy information for IE Settings.
        RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\\Connections", true);
        byte[] defConnection = (byte[])RegKey.GetValue("DefaultConnectionSettings");
        byte[] savedLegacySetting = (byte[])RegKey.GetValue("SavedLegacySettings");
        if (set)
        {
            defConnection[8] = Convert.ToByte(9);
            savedLegacySetting[8] = Convert.ToByte(9);
        }
        else
        {
            defConnection[8] = Convert.ToByte(1);
            savedLegacySetting[8] = Convert.ToByte(1);
        }
        RegKey.SetValue("DefaultConnectionSettings", defConnection);
        RegKey.SetValue("SavedLegacySettings", savedLegacySetting);
    }
```

or simply you can change registry settings given below

To disable proxy:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000000
```

To enable proxy:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000001
```

To change proxy:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"MigrateProxy"=dword:00000001
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000001
"ProxyHttp1.1"=dword:00000000
"ProxyServer"="http://ProxyServername:80"
"ProxyOverride"="<local>"
```

Comment: This is the wrong way to do it, it doesn't apply without a relog/restart and requires that the settings never change which they might.